# Vue does not from .js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have the script and ntmk in one file, then everything works.

```
<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="task.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Привет, Vue!'
        }
    })
</script>
```

Console:
vue:6 ReferenceError: message is not defined

```
at hn.eval (eval at xa (vue:6), <anonymous>:3:65)
at hn.fn._render (vue:6)
at hn.<anonymous> (vue:6)
at St.get (vue:6)
at new St (vue:6)
at hn.$mount (vue:6)
at hn.$mount (vue:6)
at hn._init (vue:6)
at new hn (vue:6)
at app.js:1
```

But if you put it into a separate file, it stops working:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>
```

```
app.js:
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message:"test"
    }

})
```

Comment: you don't have a `message` property defined in your last example

Comment: fixed. But not work.